# Is there a phrase for 'attending for the longest time'?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms, superlative-degree

I am trying to find a phrase to replace 'longest-serving'. It is in regards to a customer who is the customer who has come to a store for the longest amount of time so they are not really 'serving' more like 'longest-attending' but obviously this does not sound very nice, something along those lines.
Any ideas?
THANKS

Answer (score 1):

The term *[long-standing](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/long-standing)* means

> Having existed or continued for a long time:
> *a long-standing tradition*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

You could say *most long-standing customer*.

Perhaps you might also say *longest-standing customer*, but long-standing is a fairly fixed term, and that neologistic phrase might conjure up images of someone waiting in line for the most extended period.

**P.S.** I wouldn't use this term if you are in the seating business.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the expression ***loyal customer***

[Customer loyalty](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/customer-loyalty):

> - (noun [U] UK    US    Commerce-Marketing)
> - the fact of a ​customer ​buying ​products or ​services from the same ​company over a ​long ​period of ​time:

(Cambridge Business English Dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

adjectives I might use that suggest a more temporal context: seasoned, veteran, time-tested, proven, dedicated, loyal, diligent

nouns suggesting loyalty: supporter, devotee, fan, patron, regular, habitue, customer, advocate